# Rのロジスティック回帰分析が正しく実行されない

Tags: r

こんにちは。Rを使い始めたばかりの初心者です。この度初めて質問させていただきます。

現在Rを使ったロジスティック回帰分析を試みているのですが、説明変数に指定した量的変数のGDP(国内総生産）がなぜかまとめて（？）処理されず、以下のようになってしまいます。どうすれば解決できますでしょうか。初歩的な質問でしたら申し訳ありません。恐れ入りますが、何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

---

> unit<-read.csv("unit.csv",  na = ".")
>   model_1 <- glm(costlyA ~ GDP, data = unit,family = binomial(link = "logit"))
>   Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'GDP' not found
>   model_1 <- glm(costlyA ~ gdp, data = unit,family = binomial(link = "logit")
>   + )
>   summary(model_1)

Call:
glm(formula = costlyA ~ gdp, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = unit)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.22931  -0.62796  -0.00008  -0.00008   2.68735

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        1.3863     0.7906   1.754 0.079510 .  
gdp1.00E+11      -20.9524  4064.6349  -0.005 0.995887    
gdp1.01E+11      -20.9524  2069.6109  -0.010 0.991923    
gdp1.02E+11       -2.9267     0.9096  -3.218 0.001293 ** 
gdp1.02E+12       18.1798  5377.0065   0.003 0.997302    
gdp1.03E+11      -20.9524  3584.6711  -0.006 0.995336    
gdp1.04E+11      -20.9524  3242.4570  -0.006 0.994844    
gdp1.05E+13       -2.7726     0.9129  -3.037 0.002388 ** 
gdp1.07E+11      -20.9524  3802.1178  -0.006 0.995603    
gdp1.07E+12      -20.9524  7604.2355  -0.003 0.997802    
gdp1.08E+11      -20.9524  5377.0065  -0.004 0.996891    
gdp1.09E+12      -20.9524  5377.0065  -0.004 0.996891    
gdp1.10E+11      -20.9524  1996.9702  -0.010 0.991629    
gdp1.11E+12      -20.9524  4064.6349  -0.005 0.995887    
gdp1.11E+13       -3.0603     0.9071  -3.374 0.000742 ***

gdp1.12E+11      -20.9524  2467.1399  -0.008 0.993224    

gdp1.12E+13       -3.4340     0.9525  -3.605 0.000312 ***
gdp1.13E+11      -20.9524  7604.2355  -0.003 0.997802    
gdp1.15E+11       -3.5835     0.9501  -3.772 0.000162 ***
gdp1.16E+12      -20.9524  2874.1310  -0.007 0.994183    
gdp1.17E+11      -20.9524  4390.3075  -0.005 0.996192    
gdp1.17E+12       18.1798  5377.0065   0.003 0.997302    
gdp1.19E+12       -1.0986     1.0992  -0.999 0.317588    
gdp1.20E+12       -2.5649     0.9757  -2.629 0.008566 **

---

コメント頂いた方、ご返信頂きありがとうございます。コメント欄にて返信させていただきたいのですが、どうしても長くなってしまいますので編集という形でこちらで一部回答させていただきたく思います（まだこのコミュニティーに慣れておらず勝手がわからないもので…不適切でしたら申し訳ないです）。

1．class(unit$gdp)、summary(unit)につきまして

class(unit$gdp)
[1] "factor"

> summary(unit)
>     gdp               loggdp         gdp.per.capita     
>    2.26E+12   : 128   12.35483662: 128   1709.591808: 128   
>    64464547915: 115   10.80932094: 115   645.4650067: 115  
>    1.95E+11   : 105   11.29020978: 105   1210.158769: 105  
>    2.09E+12   : 105   12.32011832: 105   1596.470003: 105   
>    3.33E+11   : 103   10.85958392: 100   706.7574751: 100   
>    72374224249: 100   10.7451703 :  95   571.1622759:  95   
>    (Other)    :7313   (Other)    :7321   (Other)    :7321

conflict     costlyA          costly
 Min.   :0.000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:1.0000  
 Median :1.000   Median :0.0000   Median :1.0000  
 Mean   :1.005   Mean   :0.1438   Mean   :0.9133  
 3rd Qu.:1.000   3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
 Max.   :5.000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000

combat       costly.combat    
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:1.0000   1st Qu.:0.00000  
 Median :1.0000   Median :0.00000  
 Mean   :0.8843   Mean   :0.01493  
 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0.00000  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000

やはりgdp,loggdp,gdp.per.captaがおかしいですね…（costlyA~costly.combatはダミー変数ですので問題はないように思います）念のため分析する前のcsvファイルの時点で文字列等になっていないか確認はしていますが…

2．「GDP(国内総生産）がなぜかまとめて（？）処理されず」につきまして

GDP自体は量的変数ですので、想定では

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -6.3811     3.5147  -1.816   0.0694 .

### previous      0.8085     0.5851   1.382   0.1670

Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '***' 0.01 '' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

のpreviousのように一つの変数としてまとめて扱われるはずなのですが、分析結果を見ると「gdp1.00E+11」「gdp1.01E+11」のようにデータ一つ一つが個別の変数のように扱われているように見受けられます。なぜ量的変数として処理されないのかがわからずこちらでご質問させていただきました。

Comment: `class(unit$gdp)`と`summary(unit)`はどうなっていますか？ (gdpはちゃんとnumericになっていますか？)

Comment: 「GDP(国内総生産）がなぜかまとめて（？）処理されず」というのは、どのような現象なのでしょうか？　「Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'GDP' not found」というエラーは、gdpの代わりにGDPを使ったためです(Rは変数名の大文字と小文字を区別します)

Comment: @Fumu 7 Fumu 7様、ご回答いただきありがとうございます。私のケアレスミスだったようで…無事解決いたしました。この度はありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、gdpの行に、数値として認識できないデータがあるためだと思われます。
`read.csv`は`1.01E+11`という記載方法には対応しているため、それ自体は問題ありませんが、数値として認識できない行が一つでもあると、数値型として認識されず、質的変数としての解析になってしまいます。

数値以外の行や、ファイル頭や末に必要のない行がないかご確認ください。
ファイル作成者の情報や合計や平均などの行をファイルに含んでしまってこういったエラーが起こることが多いです。

不審な部分が見つからない場合は、最初の10行くらいを別で保存して試してみて、それでいけるようであれば、徐々に範囲を広げて探していくことになります。

きちんと読み込まれれば`class(unit$gdp)`は`numeric`になるはずです。

Comment: 様　ご回答いただきありがとうございます。確認したところ7セルほどエラーの出ているものがあり修正したところ無事量的変数として解析されました！いくつかの国際機関からデータを引っ張ってきたのですが国の表記にそれぞれ若干の違いがありそれが原因でエラーが出ていたようです。すべて直したつもりでいたのですが…汗初心者云々以前に私のケアレスミスだったようです…ただkcrt 様にいろいろと教えていただきよりRに対する理解が深まりました。これからまた精進いたします。この度はご丁寧にありがとうございました。